# How to store staff ID into tempdata when the user typed in their StaffNRIC

Tags: c#, asp.net

i will first give a quick rundown of my current code.
My code is a login function which compares and checks for what the user entered and to see whether it is correct in the database, if it is correct the user can log in and different view pages will be display according to what is their role. Currently, i am using temp data to store what they typed in as their StaffNRIC and show it when they are logged in and possibly use the tempdata for further functions. However, how can i get the Staff ID if the tempdata can only store what the user typed in but i want the Staff ID of what their NRIC is. The commented lines are what i have tried to no avail
when i try the commented lines, it shows this error
InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Infrastructure.DefaultTempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Starbucks.Models.StaffModel]'.

This is my code below

```
'`
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Verify(Account acc)
    {
        connectionString();
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "select * from Staff where StaffNRIC='" + acc.StaffNRIC + "' and StaffPassword='" + acc.StaffPassword + "' and StaffAccountStatus = 'Approved'";
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();   
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
            TempData["StaffNRIC"] = acc.StaffNRIC;
            //var staff = _context.Staff.Where(p => p.StaffNRIC == acc.StaffNRIC);
            //var staff = _context.Staff.Any(p => p.StaffNRIC == acc.StaffNRIC);
            //if(staff.Any(p => p.StaffNRIC == acc.StaffNRIC)
            //TempData["test"] = staff;
            while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr["StaffRole"].ToString() == "Manager")
                    {
                    
                    con.Close();
                        return RedirectToAction("ManagerHome", "Manager");//wherever you want to return the user to 
                    }
                    else if (dr["StaffRole"].ToString() == "Admin")
                    {
                    
                    con.Close();
                        return RedirectToAction("AdminHome", "Admin");
                    }
                    else if (dr["StaffRole"].ToString() == "Part-Timer")
                    {
                   
                    con.Close();
                        return RedirectToAction("PartTimerHome", "PartTimer");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        return View( "Login");
                    }
                }
            }
        ViewBag.Message = "Wrong NRIC and Password or Account not approved";
        return View("Login");
    }`'
```

Below is my HTML code for what will be displayed after they log in

'`
@{

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLayout.cshtml";
```

}

## @ViewData["Title"]

```
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">

    
    <main role="main" class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Welcome back Admin</h1>
        @{
            var tempDataEmployeet = TempData["StaffNRIC"] as StaffModel; //need typcasting
            TempData.Keep(); // retains all strings values

        }
    <h2>@TempData["test"]</h2>
    </main>

</div>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Log Out
`'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BLRT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do the following?

```
var staff = _context.Staff.FirstOrDefault(p => p.StaffNRIC == acc.StaffNRIC);
```

You were using `Where` before, which does not execute the query against the database, it merely adds a condition to the yet-to-be-executed query.

When you want to store the result(s) of a query somewhere, you need to make sure the query is executed. These are some of the functions that will execute the query:

- `ToArray` / `ToList`: returns a list of 0 or more query results
- `FirstOrDefault`: returns either one result or null
- `First`: returns one result or throws an exception
- `Any`: returns a boolean indicating if a result exists, but it won't return the result itself.